# How to print UDT as shown in CQL Shell with Java driver

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Somebody knows how to print my UDT so it shows in console as it shows in CQL Shell? This:

```
rs = session.execute(statement);
row = rs.one();
resultUDT = row.getUdtValue(0);
System.out.println(resultUDT);
```

Gives me the Objects name

```
com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.data.DefaultUdtValue@6f378182
```

I also tried with same result:

```
System.out.println(resultUDT.toString());
```

I am looking for something like:

```
{param1: 6, param2: 10,param3: [2829547778, 1927366853, 2775082582, 4232025523, 2258965237, 2897381885, 3224321316], ...}
```

Probably converting somehow to JSON?

I'd appreciate any hint. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience. Found it quite fast: getFormattedContents()

Comment: If you want further customizations, you can use following approach as well: https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/3790/files#diff-0e752484628387aa3d91b8f54c7ba777R110